# Generics Dynamic Type

Tags: generics

I have a the following method signature in an utility class

```
public void Navigate<TDestinationViewModel>(){//Implementation omitted}
```

Now another class has the following method

```
public void Navigate(object navigateParam)
```

Inside this method I want to call the method in the utility class by doing something like the following

```
UtilityClass.Navigate<typeof(navigateParam)>();
```

In essence I dont know the type of the parameter being passed into the method.  How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Your class seems to be abstract and your method defines a useless generic because only classes and method parameters can have generics.
It is also impossible to pass values as generics to methods.

Correct should be:

```
public void Navigate(TDestinationViewModel param){//Implementation omitted}

And then UtilityClass.Navigate(navigateParam);
```

Or if you want to use generics then

```
public class Navigator<T extends TDestinationViewModel> {
  public void Navigate(T param){//Implementation omitted}
}
UtilityClass.Navigate(navigateParam);
```

Hope that helps

Attention! An a static method cannot have an instance! So a generic of the class can not apply to static method, because it is instanceless! To use generic you need an object instance of the class defing the generic. But in your problem you don't need generics anyway, the Baseclass TDestinationViewModel should be enough.